# Server-Sent-Events / Nginx Proxy breaks reconnect (How to turn off nginx 502 errors for proxy unavailable?)

Tags: node.js, nginx, server-sent-events

I have nginx setup to proxy Server Sent Events from a node.js instance. In general it's working great, but I'm running into a problem when the backend (node.js) server goes down for some reason. In that situation the browser (tested with Chrome so far) will only try to reconnect once and then simply stop, rather than connect over and over again until the connection is reestablished.

I believe this happens because nginx is returning a 502 error which Chrome for some reason interprets as "stop trying to reconnect". I think this could be solved by somehow telling nginx to simply drop the connection (just like the upstream server is doing) rather than returning a 502 page. I looked through the nginx documentation but couldn't find an answer. Any idea on how to do this?